# how to locate a same folder on different machines on different directory?

Tags: python, file, directory, hard-coding

I have two folders named `Student` and `Faculty` in the directory `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Pythontraining`. I need to save totally 10 files inside `Student` folder and 3 files inside the `Faculty` folder.I need to do the same in another system where the `Student` and `Faculty` folders are present in different directory(say: `/home/documents/college`).How to store the file into the respective folders on two different machines without hardcoding the path?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, you have multiple solutions :

**Create environment variable on each machine, and inside the script do stuff like this :**

```
import os
student_path = os.environ['STUDENT_PATH']
faculty_path = os.environ['FACULTY_PATH']

print(student_path, faculty_path)
```

> Personal opinion : I don't like to configure my scripts using environment variables as the ones you chose may be used by another software + it is always messy to debug

---

**Use [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/argparse.html)**

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s", "--student")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--faculty")

args = parser.parse_args()
student_path = args.student
faculty_path = args.faculty

print(student_path, faculty_path)
```

And then call your script like this and adapt this line depending on the machine

```
python <yourscript> -s <student_path> -f <faculty_path>
```

> Personal opinion : I use arguments when I want to control a small amount of parameters on my scripts to change its behavior (verbose, nb of cpus, ...).

---

**Create a config file and use [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)**

config.ini file

```
[Paths]
student_path=<path_on_machine>
faculty_path=<path_on_machine>
```

Usage on script :

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
student_path = config.get('Paths', 'student_path')
faculty_path = config.get('Paths', 'faculty_path')

print(student_path, faculty_path)
```

And then deploy different `config.ini` files on each machine (tools like [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) can help you to automate this)

> Personal opinion : I use config files when I need to adapt parameters when deploying on new machines. I don't like to use arguments for this purpose as I don't want to specify the same values every time I use my script (often these kind of parameters don't have good default values).

---

**Create a module**

You can also create a module to store these parameters instead of a config file.

my_config.py

```
student_path="<path_on_machine>"
faculty_path="<path_on_machine>"
```

And then import it

script.py

```
import my_config

print(my_config.student_path, my_config.faculty_path)
```

> I don't have any personal opinion on config files vs config modules. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208323/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-the-configparser-instead-of-a-regular-python-py-fil) if you want some elements of comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) library for finding destination folder path. It's working best if you have only one folder for each search name:

```
import os

start = "/home/"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start):
    found = False
    for dirname in dirnames:
        if dirname == 'Student':
            full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        break
```

Output:

/home/.../Student

Comment: What if the folder 'Student' is present in multiple directory?

Comment: I'd say that it is dangerous to use walk instead of config files. You cannot be sure of the behavior of your script (especially if you have multiple student directories) and you may override important files. Be cautious.