# Module attribute import

Tags: python

I'm not sure why I can't import the `db_password` variable.

Running db_setup gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    passwd=dbconfig.db_password)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I'm missing something but i'm not sure what.

I can open up an interperter and import `dbconfig` as well as call `dbconfig.db_password'

`db_setup.py`

```py
import pymysql
import dbconfig

connection = pymysql.connections(host='localhost', user=dbconfig.db_user, passwd=dbconfig.db_password)
```

`dbconfig.py`

```py
db_user='username'
db_password='password'
```

I expect the module to pass the variable `'password'`

Comment: if you want a config file with username and password I think the best way is to use configparser library ;) https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: The point that python tries to make is that pymysql.connections is a submodule of pymysql and not a function.

Comment: @Carlo1585 https://stackoverflow.com/a/4208528/4289380 i still have no idea if configparser is better than a simple module

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the import of `db_password` variable, the error is elsewhere :

```
import pymysql
import dbconfig

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user=dbconfig.db_user, password=dbconfig.db_password)
```

`pymysql.connections` is a module, not a function, and contains the `Connection` class that is instanciate and returned by `pymysql.connect()`

[Connection class doc](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html) :

> The proper way to get an instance of this class is to call [connect()](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html).